# setting batch variables using python

Tags: python, variables, batch-file, set

Python seems to process my attempt :

```
subprocess.call(['set' , 'logfile=cat'], shell=True)
```

It returns no errors. However when I try using logfile as a variable or do `%logfile%`, it doesn't seem to have set `logfile` as anything. How does one make batch variables from within a python script?

What I am attempting to do with this is: I have a batch script that sequentially runs several python scripts. I wanted to set a variable from within one of my python scripts that would persist throughout my batch script.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is set, but as soon as the `call` returns, that instance of the shell ends and the variable goes away.

What are you trying to accomplish exactly? This sounds like an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Oh I see. I have a batch script that sequentially runs several python scripts. I wanted to set a variable from within one of my python scripts that would persist throughout my batch script.

Comment: @user3447675 you might be able to do that using an environment variable but I'm far from sure.

Comment: Environment variables won't help here.  Child processes inherit their parent's environment, but changes to the environment made in a child process aren't reflected in the parent's environment.

Comment: @Alp I don't actually know a great way for a python script launched by a batch file to affect the rest of the batch file. I'm turning my answer to community wiki -- if you have a good solution, please edit and post it!

Comment: @adsmith It would be a security hole if a child process could unilaterally alter the execution of the parent.  You have to do something like this cooperatively:  The child can communicate the desired change back to the parent, and the parent can then make the change if it deems it appropriate to do so.

Comment: Which is kind of to say that I agree with you that this is probably an XY problem.  Nothing to change in your answer...